# Filter nested array of objects base on another array

Tags: arrays

```
let students = [{name:'Sam', subjects: [{name:'math',code:'123'},{name:'english, code:'321'}, {name: 'Tom', subjects: [{name:'math', code:'123'}]}, {name: 'Joe', subjects:[{name: 'english, code:'321'}]}]

let subject = ['english']

expectedOutput = [{name: 'Joe', subjects:[{name: 'english, code:'321'}]}]
```

Comment: Please share the attempted code.

Comment: Is this a javascript question?
The tag "arrays" says "When using this tag, in a question that is specific to a programming language, tag the question with the programming language being used."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expectedOutput = students.filter((student) => {
   student.subjects.some((student_subject) => subject.includes(student_subject.name))
})
```

Since you haven't explained what you're trying to achieve and what you tried (providing actual code), I hope this is what you needs.
If the student must match **exactly** the "subject" variable (meaning, in your case, he must have english subject and ONLY english subject) then it's a bit different and you should read @jsN00b comment under my answer

Comment: If the `subject` needs to be the only subject, this may help: `students.filter(s => s.subjects.length === 1 && subject.includes(s.subjects[0]));`. May I understand why `.map()` may be necessary in this scenario, please. Further, if the `subject` array may have more than 1, then may be this should help: `students.filter(s => s.subjects.length === subject.length && subject.includes(...s.subjects));`

Comment: True. I just didn't put much thought on this but I agree with you, it's even simpler